# In PSpice, how can I fix the current with respect to resistor?

Tags: orcad, pspice

The textbook's problem is;
The current of R4 and the voltage source are 1A and 2V respectively.
If the current source is 1A:

a) Find the mesh currents.

b) Find the power dissipated in each resistor.

c) Find voltage of current source.

d) ...

---

I drew the scheme using PSPICE, exactly same as the textbook.

How can I make R4 have 1A?

[image]

I drew

Comment: Since you already have a current source of 1A you maybe want to set the current through R4 and R5?

Comment: Actually, in the problem in textbook, the current value of R4 is given as 1A with direction left to right.

Comment: By specifying the current of R4, the voltage across of R4 (with a specified resistance) is also fixed. Therefore, both the voltage and current of the element R4 is specified and that leads to over-specification. There may not be a way to specify such an over-spec element in Pspice. And in this case, the circuit has no solution (there are no proper answers to a) b)...)

Comment: @rioraxe Thank you. You gave me a sparkle idea. I will try to add voltage source parallelly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the current to a fixed value you have to place a current source in series with the resistor.

Comment: I already tried to do that. If I add current source, current is satisfied with what I wanted. But voltage problem appears because current source has its supply(or absorbing) power.

Comment: Sure, if we fix the current we have to add a voltage drop. There's no way around that.